# Camel send to multiple end points

Tags: apache-camel, multicast

How does these two differ

```
from(endpoint).to(endpoint:a, endpoint:b)

from(endpoint).multicast().to(endpoint:a, endpoint:b)
```

couldn't find any documentation for the first

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`to(endpoint:a, endpoint:b)` is equivalent to `.to(endpoint:a).to(endpoint:b)` This means that the output from `endpoint:a` is sent to `endpoint:b`, not the original `Exchange`. Also, each endpoint is executed one after the other.

`.multicast()` sends the original `Exchange` to each defined endpoint, allows for parallel processing, and allows you to define an [AggregationStrategy](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/AggregationStrategy.html) to determine how to assemble the responses from each endpoint the original `Exchange` was sent to.

Comment: No particular reason, just forgot to click.

Answer (score 10):

Yeah as jarrad writes the difference between the two are

The first is the pipes and filters EIP (default mode in Camel). Which is documented here: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PipesAndFilters.html

The 2nd is the multicast EIP which is documented here:
http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html

All the Camel EIPs is listed here: http://camel.apache.org/eip

Comment: The link to http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html is dead

Comment: Its here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/pipeline-eip.html